# Terminal : needs full path to execute a command

Tags: applications, terminal, command-line

Let's suppose i have an application in `/Applications/MacPorts/KDE4/myapp.app/Contents/MacOS/myapp`.

When i use `cd` to reach the directory 'MacOS' and then issue the command `myapp` it says command not found.

But when i issue the command with the full path like `/Applications/MacPorts/KDE4/myapp.app/Contents/MacOS/myapp` it works.

I had the same problem with mysql inside xampp.

Why is that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`bash` in Terminal uses the content of `$PATH` to look for executables. Usually `.` (for the current directory) is not part of `$PATH` (primarily for security reasons), to run commands in the current directory type `./myapp`.

Comment: yes that was it. I hadn't thought of that but it is very logical. Both answers are the same. I didn't know which to accept so i accepted the one submitted first.

Answer (score 1):

This is because when you type "myapp" is not in the current path, just because you `cd` into a directory does not mean it will be on the path to run the program.

You need to type ./myapp  or add "./" to your path so that your shell will look in the current directory for "myapp" etc.

Comment: I strongly recommend against adding `.` to `$PATH`. A simple malicious `ls` placed in a public directory can lead to a lot of problems.